# Trying to get the right SQL Query (Joins)

Tags: sql

I've been trying to join a couple tables to get the right result.
The problem is its returning some NULL values where this shouldn't be the case.

EP.ProductId, CreateDate, IsproductActivated and Subject are returning a Null Value.I've noticed it That DossierID and dossier will return a value when I make a right join as stated below. 
Could anyone help me with my case?

```
SELECT  
     EP.ProductId                           AS [ProductId]
    ,MAX(EP.CreateDate)                     AS [CreateDate]
    ,EP.IsProductActivated                  AS [IsProductActivated]
    ,PC.EntityId                            AS [DossierID]
    ,PC.EntityDiscriminator                 AS [EntityDiscriminator]
    ,PDCP.Name                              AS [Subject]
    ,D.Name                                 AS [Dossier]

FROM 
[tblEntityProduct] AS EP

LEFT JOIN .tblPDCProduct AS PDCP
    ON  PDCP.id = EP.Productid

LEFT JOIN 
    [tblProductContainerContent] AS PCC
    ON PCC.EntityProductId = EP.ProductId 

RIGHT JOIN 
    [tblProductContainer] AS PC
    ON  PC.Id = PCC.Productcontainerid 

LEFT JOIN
    [tblDossier] AS D
    ON D.Id = PC.Entityid
WHERE PC.EntityId = 2803

    GROUP BY EP.Productid
            ,IsProductActivated 
            ,EntityId 
            ,EntityDiscriminator 
            ,PDCP.name
            ,D.name
```

[The picture below shows the result of the above query. I want the values it suppose to have instead of the NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uieHu.png)

Comment: I find right outer joins quite hard to read. Most of us avoid them completely and only work with left outer joins. You are using both in one query, which makes it very difficult to understand it. Which tables are optional, which aren't? It may be a good idea to show sample data where you are getting unexpected nulls.

Comment: The right join says: Give me product containers even when there are no products. So why are you surprised to see null products in your results? Or did you have something else in mind when you chose the right join? If so, what?

Comment: I've tried to describe what the situation is and what I would like to see. Check the imgur please. https://imgur.com/a/kHDs28t

Comment: I did before I wrote my comment. Sample data should include the source. Show some rows per table and the result you get and the result you expect instead. And don't link images. Copy and paste the tabular text instead to show the tables in your request. Or even use some platform like rextester.com or dbfiddle.uk to create some table data there, so we can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

use inner join to avoid getting null values, because The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match. for right join opposite is true of left join

```
SELECT  
     EP.ProductId                           AS [ProductId]
    ,MAX(EP.CreateDate)                     AS [CreateDate]
    ,EP.IsProductActivated                  AS [IsProductActivated]
    ,PC.EntityId                            AS [DossierID]
    ,PC.EntityDiscriminator                 AS [EntityDiscriminator]
    ,PDCP.Name                              AS [Subject]
    ,D.Name                                 AS [Dossier]

FROM 
[tblEntityProduct] AS EP

 JOIN .tblPDCProduct AS PDCP
    ON  PDCP.id = EP.Productid

 JOIN 
    [tblProductContainerContent] AS PCC
    ON PCC.EntityProductId = EP.ProductId 

 JOIN 
    [tblProductContainer] AS PC
    ON  PC.Id = PCC.Productcontainerid 

 JOIN
    [tblDossier] AS D
    ON D.Id = PC.Entityid
WHERE PC.EntityId = 2803

    GROUP BY EP.Productid
            ,IsProductActivated 
            ,EntityId 
            ,EntityDiscriminator 
            ,PDCP.name
            ,D.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This didn't work unfortunately. Now I dont get any rows back, not even null value. If I use your script and add a right join on the third join, it does return the same value as stated in my picture.

Comment: @Akkoustic share your each table's data and expected output

Comment: I've tried to describe what the situation is and what I would like to see. Check the imgur please. https://imgur.com/a/kHDs28t

Answer (score 0):

I hate right-joins.  They are basically a REQUIRE THIS TABLE regardless of the others leading up to it.  Instead, I reversed the query to put the REQUIRED Table in the first position, then LEFT-JOIN to the underlying.  Now, based on the structure / join, I would THINK that you start with a product container -- will always exist.  Each product container has stuff in it (ProductContainerContent).  Then, each content item IS an entity product to get its description.  Each container has its own Dossier which may (or not) be assigned at the time the container is being prepared.  If I am accurate, most of the LEFT-JOINs should just be standard (inner) JOINs, but lets see what this does against your data.

```
SELECT
        EP.ProductId,
        MAX(EP.CreateDate) CreateDate,
        EP.IsProductActivated,
        PC.EntityId DossierID,
        PC.EntityDiscriminator,
        PDCP.Name Subject,
        D.Name Dossier
    FROM 
        tblProductContainer PC
            LEFT JOIN tblProductContainerContent PCC
                ON  PC.Id = PCC.Productcontainerid 
                LEFT JOIN tblEntityProduct EP
                    ON PCC.EntityProductId = EP.ProductId
                    LEFT JOIN tblPDCProduct PDCP
                        ON  EP.Productid = PDCP.id
            LEFT JOIN tblDossier D
                ON PC.Entityid = D.Id
    WHERE 
        PC.EntityId = 2803
    GROUP BY 
        EP.Productid,
        IsProductActivated,
        EntityId,
        EntityDiscriminator,
        PDCP.name,
        D.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and input. This resulted in the same result as I had.  The NULL values are still here.. I'm very new to SQL so I'm not very sure where to go either..

Comment: @Akkoustic, As noted by Thorsten comment,  edit your original post.  At the bottom, show the sample tables, columns and data from each respective table you are joining to.  If there are missing values in one of the tables you are trying to get data from, that will always result in NULL.  When entering data, use SPACES between data columns not tabs.  Do for EACH table so WE can see A->B->C->D table join relationship context.